# WPF MVVM await: Cancel task does not stop my progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

I am working on a .NET 4.5 small WPF/MVVM thing and I am trying to get a progressbar to work correct together with async/await.

I have gotten things to work ok, but I am not able to cancel the task properly. Or, I think the task maybe is cancelled, but the progressbar runs the full length no matter what.

I am calling the "LongRun" method both on "Start" and "Stop", but with the optional cancellation token parameter when I want to stop. This might be an unusual way of doing things, but I think it looks ok - at least in theory :-)

Here are some code:

**ViewModel**

```
public MainViewModel()
    {
        _progress = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress);
        CountFilesCreatedCommand = new RelayCommand<IProgress<int>>(progress => LongRun(Progress));
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _tokenSource.Cancel();
        StopCountFilesCommand = new RelayCommand<CancellationToken>(token => LongRun(Progress, _tokenSource.Token));
        ProgressText = "...";
    }

    private void ReportProgress(int result)
    {
        PercentProgress = result;
    }

    private async void LongRun(IProgress<int> progress, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        try
        {
            // Start long running task here
            int i = 0;
            for (; i != 101; ++i)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // This part of the code is executed when I
                    // try to stop the Task, I can see the "Cancelled!"
                    // text flicker for a second, and then the code
                    // resume to run
                    _tokenSource.Cancel();
                    progress?.Report(PercentProgress);
                    ProgressText = "Cancelled!";
                 }
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1), token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                                    progress?.Report(i);
                ProgressText = i + "%";
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {

            //throw;
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <StackPanel>
        <!--<Button Margin="10,18,10,0" Content="Start Long Run" Height="30" Click="Button_Click_Async"/>-->
        <ProgressBar x:Name="pbStatus" Margin="10,10,10,0" Height="30" IsIndeterminate="False" Visibility="Visible" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value ="{Binding PercentProgress, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbResultat" Margin="0,10,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ProgressText}" />
        <DockPanel>
            <Button Margin="10,0" Content="Start Long Run" Height="30" Width="200" Command="{Binding CountFilesCreatedCommand}"/>
            <Button Margin="10,0" Content="Stop Long Run" Height="30" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding StopCountFilesCommand}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I have a feeling that the solution might have something to do with the XAML?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

> I am calling the "LongRun" method both on "Start" and "Stop", but with the optional cancellation token parameter when I want to stop.

That's where your problem is. When you stop, you want the *existing* call to `LongRun` to exist, not create a *new* call to `LongRun`.

Something like this would be more appropriate (assuming that this operation can only be done once, and you're enabling/disabling buttons as necessary):

```
_progress = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress);
_tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CountFilesCreatedCommand = new RelayCommand(() => LongRun(_progress, _tokenSource.Token));
StopCountFilesCommand = new RelayCommand(() => _tokenSource.Cancel());
ProgressText = "...";
```

On a side note, you should [avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (as I describe in an MSDN article). `async void` has awkward error handling semantics and is not unit testable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Stephen. I created a new method for cancelling; basically doing _tokenSource.Cancel().

And the MSDN article was very clarifying, I am redesigning things a bit to use async Task instead of async void now.

Keep up the good work!